# Загрузка PHP файла как текст

Tags: файлы, php, текст

Всем привет, у меня есть форма (textarea) , в которой должен отображаться php код и так далее, как загрузить его, чтобы он не выполнялся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php и так не выполнится, а остальное htmlspecialchars

```
value="<?=htmlspecialchars(You_code)?>"
```

или

```
<pre> You_code </pre>
```

или

```
<code> You_code </code>
```

Comment: Вот смотрите мой код: 
$data['file'] = include_once(MAIN.'/template/default/'.$_POST['view_file']);
view_a_tp('admin_view',$data);

я знаю так не правильно, хочу просто наглядно объяснить что я хочу

Comment: view_a_tp << это у вас что?)

Comment: По идее вот так:

     $array = file($fname);
     $result= implode("\r\n",$array);
     $result= htmlspecialchars($result);
     view_a_tp('admin_view',$result);

Comment: всё, спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

<textarea><?php echo "<?php \n phpinfo(); ?>" ?></textarea>
как вариант 
или 
<textarea><?php echo htmlentities("<?php \n phpinfo(); ?>" ); ?></textarea>
как то так